# Prevent viewing of the download window while exporting to pdf or image in browser

Tags: html, jspdf

While importing HTML page to PDF I am getting a download  window pop up similar to the one given below

But I do not want the user to view that the pdf is downloaded but still I am able to do the download.

[image: pop up image]
I tried the following code but still i am getting a  window in the Firefox browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<body>


<script>
window.stop();
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
  pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
</script>
  <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use window.stop but no results . Request your help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question correctly that you want to create and show a pdf in another browser-tab:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<body>
  <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
</body>

<script>
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
var pdfFile;
pdf.addHTML(document.body, function() {
  console.log(pdf);
  var pdfBlob = pdf.output('blob');
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
  window.open(fileURL);
});
</script>
</html>
```

Or you can also open a pdf in onother tab by clicking on a button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<body>
  <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
  <p id="openPDFButton">Open PDF</p>
</body>

<script>
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
var pdfFile;
pdf.addHTML(document.body,function(){});
document.getElementById('openPDFButton').onclick = function(){
  var pdfBlob = pdf.output('blob');
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
  window.open(fileURL);
};
</script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!